# Passing a parameter into a method on a constructor

Tags: java, parameters, constructor

I have a problem that is pretty basic but I am struggling to get right. Basically, I have a constructor that has some methods defined on it using `this.`. I want to pass one of those methods a paramter, but I am struggling to declare it in a way that doesn't cause an error. This is my code:

```
public class Graph {
    public Graph(int[][] gA) {
        boolean[] visited = new boolean[gA.length];
        Arrays.fill(visited, 0, gA.length, false);

        //this is the bit I'm struggling with:
        this.adj(int v) = gA[v];
        this.array = gA;
        this.visited = visited;
    }

}
```

How do I get `this.adj` to accept a parameter? I also tried creating a method declaration but couldn't get this work either. Is there some kind of design pattern I should use?

Thanks

EDIT: Apologies - made a mistake in the code excerpt. `this.adj[v]` should be returning a row of the `gA` array, which it only has access to within the constructor, so I cannot move the function outside.

Answer (score 2):

This :

```
this.adj(int v) = adj(v);
```

Is the wrong way. Just use:

```
adj(v); // Call the method adj with the parameter v
```

Since you are calling it in the constructor, hence it does not matter if the method is `static` or not. A constructor can call both of them.

---

**Edit:**

> I want adj[v] to return the row of gA at v. I've edited the code above

You can do:

```
gA[v] = adj(v);
```

Comment: Apologies I had actually made an error in the code above - `adj(v)` actually refers to a row in the array `gA[v]`

Comment: So, you want to pass the row as the parameter to the function `adj` ?

Answer (score 0):

why you dont just call the method you defined??

```
public class Graph {
    private YOUR_TYPE adj;
    public Graph(int[][] gA) {
        boolean[] visited = new boolean[gA.length];
        Arrays.fill(visited, 0, gA.length, false);

        //this is the bit I'm struggling with:
        this.adj  = adj(v);
        this.array = gA;
        this.visited = visited;
    }

   YOUR_TYPE adj(int v){
    return .... something from YOUR_TYPE
   }

}
```